# How to handle ReferenceField migration with flask mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-admin, flask-mongoengine

I've implemented a simple flask application with mongodb that now needs some upgrades.

Let's say to have a class model for Foo and a class model for Bar in which there is a reference field to Foo

```
class Foo(Document):
  title = StringField()

class Bar(Document):
  name = StringField()
  foo = ReferenceField('Foo')
```

Let the flask application runs doing its job for a while, so that now there are some data in the DB.

Due to requirements changes, we need to refactor the Foo class subclassing it from a new super class:

```
class SuperFoo(Document):
  meta = { 'allow_inheritance': True,}
  #[...]

class Foo(SuperFoo):
  #[...]

class Bar(Document):
  name = StringField()
  foo = ReferenceField('Foo')
```

The code above works well with an empty database.

But in case of some data in it, mongoengine raises an Exception when a flask admin tries to show a Bar instance (in edit mode)

```
File "[...]/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 1124, in __get__
    raise DoesNotExist('Trying to dereference unknown document %s' % value)
mongoengine.errors.DoesNotExist: Trying to dereference unknown document DBRef('super_foo', ObjectId('5617a08939c6c70cbaa2af6e'))
```

I suppose data model needs to be migrated in some way.

How?

thanks,
alessandro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little analyis I came up to solve the problem.

Mongoengine creates a new collection `super_foo`.

Documents of every inherited class goes into this `super_foo` collection with an additional attribute `_cls`.
The value is the CamelCased hierarchy path of that class. In this example documents will have

`'_cls': 'SuperFoo.Foo'` field.

What I've done is to copy every document from the old `foo` collection into the new `super_foo` one, adding the field `{'_cls': u'SuperPlesso.Plesso'}` to each.

The migration function should look like:

```
def migrationFunc():
    from pymongo.errors import DuplicateKeyError
    from my.app import models

    _cls = {'_cls': u'SuperFoo.Foo'}

    fromOldCollection = models.Foo._collection
    toSuperCollection = models.Superfoo._collection

    for doc in fromOldCollection.find():
        doc.update(_cls)
        try:
            toSuperCollection.insert(doc)
        except DuplicateKeyError:
            logger.error('...')
```

Then I updated the base code of the models with the actual new hierarchy:

```
class SuperFoo(Document):
  meta = { 'allow_inheritance': True,}
  #[...]

# was class Foo(Document)
class Foo(SuperFoo):
  #[...]
```

Al back references to `Foo` in `Bar` collections, or elsewhere, are preserved.